# Get function arity in scala

Tags: scala, function, arity

Is there a way to retrieve the arity of a function? For instance, given the following function:

```
def moop[I,O](func: I => O) = {
  val arity = I.???
  ???
}
```

How would I get the arity of `func`?

Comment: How could it be anything other than 1?

Comment: For instance `I` could be a tuple type

Comment: AFAIK, tuples are still one operand.

Comment: What do you want to do based on the arity?

Comment: Due to the use in a native library, I need to generate a string with a number of literal equal to the arity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `I` is a tuple, you can call the `productArity` method on it which is inherited from [`Product`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.Product).

If you have an object of which you only know it is some kind of function, you will have to check against the (finite) set of `FunctionN` classes since there is no common supertype as for tuples. It looks like we currently have `Function0` up to `Function22`.

Comment: I think I'll resort to sbt-boilerplate to generate specific creation functions for all possible arities.